# Mongoose doesn't catch errors after saving: TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

I was using Mongoose `4.13.11` and my code was working as expected but as soon as I upgraded to `5.0.15` I started to have the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined` when I try to save my object and an error is found.

I've read around the issue seems to be that the `Save()` function does not return a `Promise`, I am using `bluebird` and everything was working fine on the previous `Mongoose` version `4.13.11`

What am i missing or doing wrong because the `.catch()` should work as implemented.

**app.ts**

```
mongoose.Promise = bluebird;
mongoose.connect(mongoUrl).then(
  () => { /** ready to use. The `mongoose.connect()` promise resolves to undefined. */ },
).catch(err => {
  console.log("MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running. " + err);
  // process.exit();
});
```

**Home.ts**

```
let user: userInterface = {
        email: "foo@bar.com",
        firstName: "Brian",
        lastName: "Love",
        password: "as",
        role: 1,
        accountType: 1
    };

    var newUser = new User(user);      // create a new instance of the User model

    // save the newUser and check for errors
    var a=  newUser.save(function(err) {
        if (err){
            return err;
        }
        res.json({ message: 'User created!' });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: Working before? Somehow I doubt that. `newUser.save(function(err) {` should be `newUser.save().then(() => */ something on success /* ).catch(` or even just `newUser.save().then(null, err => { ... })`, since afterall `catch()` is just sugar for the second argument to `then()` anyway. You don't mix callbacks and promises like this, and if somehow that was not throwing an error before, then it was a bug.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes, was working perfectly. I tried your code and now i get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` its not returning a promise

Comment: Well [`.save()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-save) either takes a `callback` as an argument ( like you tried ) or returns a `Promise` like I am showing. But never **both** like your listing shows. If you are getting `Cannot read property 'then'`, I would suspect this is not a standard mongoose `Document` object, and that something else in your code is actually breaking this. And your `callback` as well of course.

Comment: @NeilLunn There is an error being executed (as expected as i am testing the `catch()` ) `errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: admin.users index: email_1 dup key: { : "foo@bar.com" }',` So the `err` callback is being used... but then every single tutorial handless error in the same way... i dont know why this `err` is not a promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches to invoke save in mongoose

- Promise
- Callback

**Promise**

```
newUser.save().
    then((data) =>{
        console.log("saved data ",data);
        res.json({ message: 'User created!' });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.json({ message: 'User not created!' });
    });
```

**Callback**

```
newUser.save(function(err,data) {
    if (err){
        console.log(error);
        res.json({ message: 'User not created!' });
    }
    else{
        console.log("saved data ",data);
        res.json({ message: 'User created!' });
    }
})
```

You could enable promise in mongoose by setting this

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

**Documentation** http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html